When G-d spoke to a particular individual, does anybody else hear what He is saying?
At one point, the whole world heard G-d during the revelation in Mt. Sinai, but when G-d specifically spoke to someone, could anyone have eavesdropped and heard what He said or could it be only heard by the person He was talking to? For example, if G-d was revealing a prophecy to a prophet and somehow, someone was in the vicinity where G-d and the prophet are communicating, could the bystander hear/be privy to what was being said/communicated?

Given omnipotence and omniscience, wouldn't it just be whatever God wanted?

See the second and fourth Rashi on Vayikra 1:1

Samuel heard the LORD calling to him while Eli did not (1 Samuel 3)

@RyanPierceWilliams to be fair, Eli was in a different room at the time

"if G-d was revealing a prophecy to a prophet and somehow, someone was in the vicinity where G-d and the prophet are communicating, could the bystander hear/be privy to what was being said/communicated?" - according to Maimonides, prophecy was conveyed using metaphoric imagery - "When a prophet is informed of a message in a vision, it is granted to him in metaphoric imagery"- according to this, maybe we can say that the prophecy is also heard within that person and not by others? Just thinking out loud :)

@DoubleAA +1, that was my first thought, and the answer seems to be that we have examples of other's hearing and not hearing etc. but given that some of His way's follow a system He put in place, it isn't always right to invoke omnipotence

All prophecies except for Moshe’s were given through dreams per the Rambam

@CuriousYid now what about just a mere conversation between G-d and any of, say, the Patriarchs or Matriarchs, or even Hagar, or anyone not named Moshe Rabbeinu?

@ddas91600 A lot of the time it appears to have actually been an angel - despite speaking in the first person as if God. For example, the angel in the Burning Bush from whom we get God’s name. Or the angel that wrestled with Jacob.

@DoubleAA Yes, but you can say that about everything. The question can be framed as asking if Hashem wanted to allow bystanders to hear the prophecy despite it not being directed at them, or if He communicated prophecy in such a manner that only the primary recipient could receive it; or, if that depended on the prophecy, or type of prophecy, or prophet, or whatever.

@Qwertrl that'd probably be a better question

According to the Rambam, prophecy didn't involve sound waves. The Ran disagrees, but explicitly says the sound was directly only to the intended prophet. I think the Ran's awake prophecy (which I think also means only Moshe's) was a kind of miracle - sound with no physical cause.  If my sefarim weren't all in boxes and I could give sources, I would have posted details as an official answer.

@MichaBerger please make an answer, please, I implore you

The Alshich describes (Shir Hashirim 1:2) prophesy as Hashem speaking to someone through their soul. Even though "the ears hear", they are hearing internally.
The Sinai event was an exception, where Hashem tore open the heavens.
It seems the default case is that nobody else can hear, unless Hashem makes an exception.

In 1 Shmuel 3:1-10, G-d speaks to Samuel and Eli doesn't hear it:

1And the lad Samuel was serving the Lord before Eli. Now the word of
the Lord was withheld in those days; vision had not broken through.
2And it was on that day, that Eli was lying in his place, and his eyes
had begun to grow dim; he could not see. 3And the lamp of God had not
yet gone out, and Samuel was lying down. In the Temple of the Lord,
where the Ark of God was. 4The Lord called to Samuel, and he said,
"Here I am." 5And he ran to Eli, and said, "Here I am, for you have
called me." And he said, "I did not call. Go back and lie down." And
he went and lay down. 6And the Lord continued to call again to Samuel,
and Samuel arose, and went to Eli, and said, "Here I am, for you have
called me.'' And he said, "I have not called, my son. Go back and lie
down." 7Now, Samuel had not yet known the Lord, and the word of the
Lord had not yet been revealed to him. 8And the Lord continued to call
Samuel for the third time; and he arose and went to Eli, and said,
"Here I am, for you called me." And Eli understood that that the Lord
was calling the youth. 9And Eli said to Samuel, "Go, lie down. And it
shall be, if He will call you, that you shall say, 'Speak, O Lord, for
Your bondsman is listening.' " And Samuel went and lay down in his
place. 10And the Lord came and stood, and He called as at the other
times, "Samuel! Samuel!" And Samuel said, "Speak, for Your bondsman is
listening."

